Pass symbols to gdb at runtime
I am making a JIT recompiler, which means I generate blocks of code at runtime. I would like to be able to tell gdb that a host region, say
0x7f00'0ac0-0x7f00'03c0 has the name block_1000_0ac0 because in this example that host region maps to a block generated from the guest address 0x1000'0ac0.
I want this to happen from within my C++ app, so that the JIT can mark the blocks it recompiles with symbols. This will make it so that when I break in gdb I know which guest region my recompiled block maps to.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

This is absolutely possible, though it will be a significant amount of work.
GDB has a JIT plugin API, the documentation for which can be found here.  I think there's too much to describe it here.
The problem with this plugin API is it's pretty old.  I think it was added either before, or at a similar time as the Python API support.  If this was being added to GDB today then it would for sure be written as a Python extension.  As it is you may end up having to write some C code to make it work.
If after reading the docs you have more specific questions then it might be worth creating new questions on here.

There's no way to do that from my knowledge without creating intermediate debug symbol file in format like COFF at runtime, and loading it with GDB symbol-file command.
For more information, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF. Other options could be DWARF symbol.
